# How to build angular and node js together for escpos protocol?

Tags: node.js, angular, thermal-printer, escpos

sorry for my english.
I have angular front-end, node js server, thermal printer.
I had to communicate with thermal printers from angular using esc/pos protocol, so I made a node js server.
Now I do a request from angular to node and then node communicates with the printer (using ip and port).
How can I build angular and node together? So when I deploy it I don't have to start node server every time?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are refering to run it locally. There are several ways:

1. In windows 10, for example, you can run a nodejs "server" like a window service. So it runs on startup. (take a look at this repo [Forever tool](https://github.com/foreversd/forever))
2. You can use electron js: first of all generate your build of Angular project: `ng b --prod`: this will generate the dist folder with your index.html and necessary scripts. Now you can serve this static folder from your node js script: for example, with the help of [Express js](https://expressjs.com/).

```js
var express = require("express");

var app = express();


app.use(express.static("/dist/myAngularProject"));

//Add your escpos logic, ecc..

app.listen(3001, function () {
  console.log("Server listening on port 3001!");
});
```

Now if you run the comand: `node index.js`, you should see your angular app. The next step is very simple: start a new [Electron js](https://www.electronjs.org/) application, and in your main.js load your server URL:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
require("./server/myNodeJsServerIndex.js")



let win

function createWindow () {
  
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 950,
    height: 750,
    fullscreen: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      devTools:false
    }
  })


  //my node js server
  win.loadURL(`http://localhost:3001`);



  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
}


app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

With `require("./server/myNodeJsServerIndex.js")` and `win.loadURL(`http://localhost:3001`);`, it means that every time that you start the electron client, your nodejs server will start automatically.